# Python 3 two dimensional list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists that are used to assemble a third. I compare list_one to list_two and if the value of a field in list_one is located in list_two both the values from list_two are copied into list_final. If the value of a field is missing from list_two then I'd like to see a null value (None) placed into list_final. list_final would have the same number of items and in the same order as list_one:

```
list_one = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
list_two = [['seven','7'], ['five','5'], ['four','4'], ['three','3'], ['one','1']]
list_final = []
```

The value of list_final should be:

```
[['one','1'], [None,None], ['three','3'], ['four','4'], ['five','5'], [None,None], ['seven','7']]
```

The closest I've gotten is:

```
list_final = [x if [x,0] in list_two else [None,None] for x in list_one]
```

but that just fills list_final with `None`. I've looked at some tutorials but I just can't seem to wrap my brain around this concept. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `list_two` should better be (or converted to) a dictionary then you do things like `dict_two.get('seven')` to get `'7'` which makes the list comprehension much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was happening in your code:

```
list_final = [x if [x,0] in list_two else [None,None] for x in list_one]
```

1. Taking `list_one` and replace all its element with
2. Either `x` (aka keep it intact) IF `[x,0]` exists in `list_two` (**BUT**, see below)
3. ELSE replaces the current element with `[None, None]`.

And as `list_two` doesn't contain any element matching `[x,0]` (whichever is `x` in your given example), all your values are replaced with `[None, None]`.

## Working solution

```
list_one = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
list_two = [['seven','7'], ['five','5'], ['four','4'], ['three','3'], ['one','1']]

# Turns list_two into a nice and convenient dict much easier to work with
# (Could be inline, but best do it once and for all)
list_two = dict(list_two)  # {'one': '1', 'three': '3', etc}

list_final = [[k, list_two[k]] if k in list_two else [None, None] for k in list_one]
```

Mine, in the other hand:

1. Gets you exactly what you want, aka `[k, dict(list_two)[k]]`
2. But only tries to do so IF `k in list_two`
3. ELSE replaces this entry with `[None, None]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and **SUPER THANK YOU** for the explanation!

Comment: @Jarvis Hope it helps... that's what I wrote it for. Feel free to ask any question (provided you tell us what you've tried so far, etc... the usual :))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list_one = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
list_two = [['seven','7'], ['five','5'], ['four','4'], ['three','3'], ['one','1']]
final_list = [[None, None] if not any(i in b for b in list_two) else [c for c in list_two if i in c][0] for i in list_one]
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[['one', '1'], [None, None], ['three', '3'], ['four', '4'], ['five', '5'], [None, None], ['seven', '7']]
```